# OpenDocument format plugin for Mac Office 2008?

Tags: macos, plugins, openoffice, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008

Is there a plugin or script that lets Microsoft Office 2008 for Mac OS X open and save files in the OpenDocument ODF (.odt, .ods, .odp, etc.) format? I am thinking something like what you can do in Office 2007.

I realise I could use an external converter, such as OpenOffice.org, just wondering if there is a more direct way.

If such a plugin does not exist, would it be possible to manually make such a plugin? Such as via AppleScript (or anything else)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the write-up on this [page](http://lnxwalt.wordpress.com/2007/01/08/opening-odf-odt-ods-odp-etc-files/):

> Sun's ODF Plugin for Microsoft Office
>   allows users of Microsoft's product to
>   also open and save ODF (.odt, .ods,
>   and .odp) files in the corresponding
>   Microsoft application.  Available for
>   Windows operating systems. UPDATE:
>   2010-04-20: Oracle / Sun now charges
>   $90 for the plugin, with a minimum 100
>   unit order. For most of us, this means
>   that this plugin is no longer a
>   reasonable tool for our uses.

It seems there was a Sun plugin for Office although since Oracle's acquisition, they have begun to charging $90 for it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the Microsoft Office I am talking about is Microsoft Office 2008, which runs on Mac OS X, not the Windows version. So even if I were to pay $90 the plugin won't work for me...